# Normalization of complex numbers

Tags: computer-science, complex-numbers

I have a datafile which is in array form. I want to normalize all complex numbers in that array. But I dont want to use z/Abs[z] this approach. I want to use different approach like z-score. For example, in z-score you can find the standard deviation and you can normalize all numbers but I am trying to normalize complex numbers. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-Score for Real numbers:

```
Z = (X - Avg) / SD
```

The obvious approach that comes to mind, would be calculating the average & standard deviation for the real plane & imaginary plane independently.

Then we would presumably alter the formula, to use something like sqrt( sum-of-squares) approach to combine real & imaginary components or scores.

```
Zr = (Xr - AvgR) / SDr
Zi = (Xi - AvgI) / SDi
```

And finally:

```
Zc = sqrt( Zr^2 + Zi^2)
```

This would probably be the most straightforward way of producing a single Z-score from a complex number within it's distribution.

This is of course different from 'normalization', which would retain separate components and what was what I initially answered. But I believe that a single score, measuring distance from the mean, is what you're after here.

Comment: How true is it to normalize my data independently each of other. It came to my mind but I was not sure if it is the best approach.

Comment: Actually, looking at Z-Score I think you're after a measurement of distance from the distribution -- 'normalization' is a different concept. See my edited answer.

Comment: z-score was just an example. Do you know a way to normalize complex numbers except z/Abs[z]?

Comment: Well, I've given you two answers already @Isaac04..  Both of which would are good in the appropriate circumstances. Looking at your question, it looks like Z-score is most like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

you can normalize your complex vector as

```
norm = np.exp(1j*np.angle(z))
```

although it is slower but has advantage over

```
z/abs(z)
```

since if z is zero and you do above calculation you will get nan. even if you remove nan by 0 you will get 0 any way because normalized length can not be zero. If you use this 0 length normalized vector to set the phase of any other vector you will always get 0. It depends on what you are searching

alternatively you can do

```
z1=z/abs(z)
z1[np.isnan(z)]=1
```

because normalized length should be 1

regards

Comment: Do you have a source for your first suggestion?

Comment: The first expression comes from `exp(i * x) = cos(x) + i * sin(x)` and is thus simply equal to `cos(angle(z)) + i * sin(angle(z))`. That said, it's not like `angle(z)` is a well-defined quantity for z = 0 either, so you are just shifting the responsibility for handling zero/infinity to a different function.